# How to make window popup in Qt Python auto stretchable

Tags: python, qt, pyside

```
window = Window(3, 6,tss, centralNodeId, centralNode, normalised, parent, index,root,self.columns)
window.setAttribute (Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
window.setMinimumSize (1000, 100)
window.setWindowTitle ('Soft Causal Check')
window.show()
```

This is my code, Now when I add  a table to this window later after some event it stays the same height(100) . i want to make it auto adjustable . Can anybody guide me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a layout to the window, and use size policies to make the window
automatically adjust on the size of its contents.